# json delete square brackets

Tags: php, json

this php script

```
 <?php
 require('medoo.min.php');
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $database = new medoo('brickx');

 $datas = $database->select("customer", ["Companyname", "Phonenumber"]);

 $jsonresponse = array("customers"=> array());
 array_push($jsonresponse["customers"], $datas);
 echo (json_encode($jsonresponse));

 ?>
```

outputs this kind of json:

```
 {"customers":[[{"Companyname":"company1","Phonenumber":"+567890789"},{"Companyname":"company2","Phonenumber":"5678905678"}]]}
```

however i need to get rid of the square brackets and get something like

```
{"customers":{"Companyname":"company1","Phonenumber":"+567890789"},{"Companyname":"company2","Phonenumber":"5678905678"}}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What you want is not legal JSON. You have to keep at least one square bracket.

Comment: in some of the documentation of restkit the examples had json without square brackets. you are right if you say that i need at least one square bracket. the answer below is the correct one. thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$datas` is already an array, you probably want this instead:

```
$array = array('customers' => $datas);
echo json_encode($array);
```